# The URL for the default image for a newly created feed user has too many slashes

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, feed

When you create a new feed in a room, the feed user's image URL is set to the following:

```
http:////cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Img/feed-icon32.png
```

That's an awful lot of slashes at the beginning there. This doesn't seem to cause any problems in Chrome (i.e. the four-slash version [which I can't post outside a code block] and the [two-slash version](http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Img/feed-icon32.png) point to the same thing), but I'm not aware of any reason that one might want to keep all those extra slashes lying around.